# In Google Analytics, should I apply delay before redirection?

Tags: google-analytics

Using Google Analytics, I am tracking clicks on a link (The link is of the same website).

Is it necessary to apply some delay before redirection after tracking the click using trackPageViews?

I see people suggest delay on outbound link but I guess, the same rationale applies to the link that takes users to the same website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is really whether or not the tracking pixel request (from `_trackPageview`) has completed before you leave the current page.

So, yes -- if the link is opening up in the existing window, you'll want to add a delay on following the link, regardless of staying on the site or not.

BTW, while using `_trackPageview` for tracking clicks will work, it also inflates the actual page view count for your site -- you might want to use event tracking (with `_trackEvent`) instead. See  [Event Tracking Guide](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide)